# PyCharm's debugger gives up when hitting copy.deepcopy()

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

PyCharm's debugger works perfectly, except when hitting lines that contain the built-in method copy.deepcopy(). Stepping over them causes the program to run to conclusion, as if no debugger were running. I have tried stepping into deepcopy(), but I always seem to get caught in a recursive loop. The code runs fine, debugger or no debugger, I just cannot run the debugger after an deepcopy() operations, which is irritating.

pdb.set_trace() works fine, but ultimately I'd like to use PyCharm's debugger, and I'm REALLY curious as to what is happening here.

Comment: This is very strange and still happening with `Pycharm 2019.1.2`. Have you found out what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your __getattr__ method to ignore attributes starting with double underscore. This works for objects, that do not have many attached objects and prevents PyCharm from disconnecting the debugger:

```
def __getattr__(self, k):
    if k.startwith("__"):
        raise AttributeError
```

However, for larger objects (in terms of the hierarchy) you need to define own __deepcopy__ method for each object involved in deepcopy.

Answer (score 0):

did you try import the module individually by doing :

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

i got the same error as pyCharm didn't recognize deepcopy by itself

Comment: i did it and it worked for me. I even ported this code to iPython and it worked fine there. Not sure what is causing issues in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It happend to me too, after a lot of trial and error I figured out what was causing it, (but I don't know why) The object I was deepcopy ing implemented getattr

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
     return self[item]
```

it did work, it just stopped the debugger.  When I commented out this lines it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pydevd.settrace()` as a first line of the function you try to debugging, or right after `deepcopy()`